# как открыть и закрыть изображение Python

Tags: python, ос

Нужно в цикле открывать файл изображения и через 3 секунды закрыть его. Пробовал два способа, но ни один не работает как следует.

Способ 1 (окно открывается, но изображение не отображается):

```
import cv2
import time
for i in range(2):
    img = cv2.imread('image.png')
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    time.sleep(3)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Способ 2 (окно открывается, но не знаю как его закрывать):

```
import os
for i in range(2):
    a = subprocess.Popen('treugolnik'+'\\'+str(treugolnik[i]), shell = True)
```

Comment: Используйте вместо `time.sleep(3)` `cv2.waitKey(3)` или `cv2.waitKey(3000)` (не помню: секунды или миллисекунды там).

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо!!!